# snscrape error when attempting to scrape from mastodon

Tags: python, mastodon

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to test out snscrape for scraping posts from Mastodon, using @pomological@botsin.space as a test case. (A bot that posts public domain fruit illustrations.) I think I'm following the correct format but it keeps giving me this error. Can anyone help? It gives me a similar error when I try either the "mastodon-profile" or "mastodon-toots" scrapers. I have used snscrape to scrape tweets from twitter many times and haven't had this problem.
The command I'm using is `snscrape mastodon-profile @pomological@botsin.space`.

```
C:\Windows\system32>snscrape mastodon-profile @pomological@botsin.space
2023-04-04 11:49:23.086 CRITICAL snscrape._cli Dumped stack and locals to C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\snscrape_loca
ls_3xbv51be
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\snscrape.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\_cli.py", line 320, in main
    for i, item in enumerate(scraper.get_items(), start = 1):
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\mastodon.py", line 279, in get_items
    yield from self._entries_to_items(soup.find('div', class_ = 'activity-stream').find_all('div', class_ = 'entry'), r.url)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I've done some minimal python programming, but I'm pretty out of my depth here. Any assistance would be appreciated. I may have missed something obvious!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Feels like either the Mastodon profile page of this account does not have the expected HTML structure that snscrape is looking for. Either that or there might be server-side issues on Mastodon's end that are preventing snscrape from retrieving the data.

Comment: I forgot to mention above; I tried with a few different Mastodon profiles that were running on different instances, so I'm not sure either of those options would explain it.

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question above so that the community can try to reproduce and understand.

Comment: It was at the top of the log I pasted in, but I have added it to the body of the question for clarity.